# Retrieve Device Motion data only once - Core Motion

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion

I'm using Core Motion to see if the phone is facing upwards or downwards, and I only need to retrieve the data once. Here is some of my code:

```
let manager = CMMotionManager()
manager.showsDeviceMovementDisplay = true

// "Pull data" - since I only need it once
manager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0 / 60.0
manager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(using: .xMagneticNorthZVertical)

// Repeats set to false since I only need it once - but same problem even when set to true
self.timer = Timer(fire: Date(), interval: 1.0 / 60.0, repeats: false) { _ in
    print("Timer started")
    if let motionData = manager.deviceMotion?.gravity.z {
        print("Successfully unwrapped")
        if 0.7...1 ~= motionData { // Facing downwards
            print("Facing downwards")
            position = .downwards(motionData)
        } else if -1...(-0.7) ~= motionData { // Facing upwards
            print("Facing upwards")
            position = .upwards(motionData)
        } else {
            print("Position uknown")
            position = .unknown
        }
    }
}
RunLoop.current.add(self.timer!, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.default)
```

However, I never reach `"Successfully unwrapped"`. From my attempts to debug, I found that `manager.isDeviceMotionActive` is never set to `true`, even though I called `startDeviceMotionUpdates(using: .xMagneticNorthZVertical)`. Why could that be?

Comment: There is a [simpler way to do this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-check-whether-an-iphone-or-ipad-is-upside-down-or-face-up)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot! And I'll probably use Combine publishers and subscribers instead of Objective-C selectors, like shown in [this Apple article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/routing-notifications-to-combine-subscribers).

Answer (score 0):

Where is this declared? is it possible your reference to the manager is deallocating?

try storing it in a property somewhere that won't get destroyed after the function is called maybe